# How should I go about modifying this jQuery UI draggable code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I've set up a jsFiddle which illustrates the whole [situation here.](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/Lt9Kb/7/) Everything works as I'd hoped, except that when you drag the red "peg" to one of the green boxes on the right, and then drag another red peg on top of it, I wish it would turn back to red when it reverts back to the box on the left.

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="peg">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="peg">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="peg">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="peg">&nbsp;</div>
</div>



<div id="game">
    <ul class="row">
        <li class="hole">&nbsp;</li>
        <li class="hole">&nbsp;</li>
        <li class="hole">&nbsp;</li>
        <li class="hole">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="row">
        <li class="hole">&nbsp;</li>
        <li class="hole">&nbsp;</li>
        <li class="hole">&nbsp;</li>
        <li class="hole">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul> </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.peg' ).draggable({
    snap: ".hole",
    snapMode: "inner",
    snapTolerance: 40,
    //scope: "zappa",
    //revert: 'invalid',
    stop: function(){
        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
    },
    //helper: "clone"
});    

$('.peg').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit'
});

$('.peg').droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event,ui){
        ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
    }
});

$('.hole').droppable({
     drop: function(e,ui) {
          $(ui.draggable).removeClass('peg').addClass('top');
     },
     //scope: "zappa"
});

$('#box').droppable({
     drop: function(e,ui) {
          $(ui.draggable).removeClass('top').addClass('peg');
     },
     //scope: "zappa"
});
```

CSS:

```
#game {
    position: absolute;
    width: 330px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 15px;
    left: 135px;
    background: wheat;
    padding: 15px;
}

.row {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: olive;
}

.hole {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
    background-color: aqua;
    opacity: 0.3;
    margin-left: 6px;
}

#box {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: wheat;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.peg {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
.space {
    height: 15px;
    width: 75px;
}

.top {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Paste your code here.  Leave the fiddle link.

Comment: its rather long- better to just look at the fiddle

Comment: Your question will be totally useless to future readers when the fiddle goes dead.  See http://sscce.org for guidelines on making this more self-contained.  You take the time to put together a good question and we'll take the time to put together some good answers.

Comment: cool, sorry folks, i was not aware fiddles were mortal, thanks!